# sort text file by first element

Tags: python, text, rank

I generate a `txt` file :

```
6034;3011;571;;;; 

61443;1571;3111;;;;

6150;2994;242;;;;

6028;26;994;;;;

12054;24;262;3011;571;;

19758.90;0;1;;;;
```

I would like to rank it from highest to lowest according to the first number of the line in order to write another `txt` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print sorted(lines, key=lambda x:float(x.split(';')[0]), reverse=True)
```

result:

```
['61443;1571;3111;;;;\n', '19758.90;0;1;;;;\n', '12054;24;262;3011;571;;\n', '6150;2994;242;;;;\n', '6034;3011;571;;;; \n', '6028;26;994;;;;\n']
```